# EF 4.1 Code First Silverlight 4 RIA public virtual ICollection<T> problem

Tags: c#, silverlight, ef-code-first, wcf-ria-services

I've got 2 EF 4.1 Code First classes:

```
public class SKUMaster {
  public string SKU { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<SKUMasterFinishedItem> SKUMasterFinishedItems { get; set; }
}

public class SKUMasterFinishedItem {
  public string SKU { get; set; }
  public int FinishedItemID { get; set; }
  public int Quantity { get; set; }
  public virtual FinishedItem FinishedItem { get; set; }
  public virtual SKUMaster SKUMaster { get; set; }
}
```

The navigation properties from SKUMasterFinishedItem are showing up on the Silverlight 4 RIA side, but SKUMaster.SKUMasterFinishedItems does not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**See this best post [Entity Framework Code-First With RIA Services](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/238377.aspx/1/10?Entity%20Framework%20Code%20First%20With%20RIA%20Services)**